# Open file with MIDlet.platformRequest()

Tags: blackberry, java-me, midlet

Is it possible to get a device to open a file on disk using the `MIDlet.platformRequest(String url)` method? I was hoping to use the following:

```
midlet.platformRequest("file:///path/to/file/file.png");
```

But this just throws a `ConnectionNotFoun`d exception. I'm specifically using the BlackBerry platform, but I **do not** have access to the proprietary BlackBerry API. File could be of any type, so obviously I'm not expecting it to handle every one.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible to open arbitrary files using platform request. MIDP 2.0 requires devices to support platform request only for URL and tel: connections. All other schemes are optional and device dependent.

Nokia S60 phones seems to support file:// as pointed out in [forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/document/Java_ME_Developers_Library/?content=GUID-EBB4BC93-74A5-48E6-88BD-A9164079DD9F.html). But you need to verify for other platforms including Blackberry.

You can look at [JSR211 Content Handler API](http://www.j2ee.me/javame/reference/apis/jsr211/) as an alternative. I believe it is supported in newer Blackberry devices.