# platformRequest not working in J2ME

Tags: java-me, media-player, nokia, nativeapplication

I'm triyng to play .mp3 file using platformRequest(). I verified the file path and it is correct. And I'm using Nokia 210 for testing. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you post your code and exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    platformRequest("file:///C:/song.mp3");
} catch (ConnectionNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I know you have already verified whether there is file or not. though check my below code once and post comment with results.

Added -

```
public boolean isFileExisted(String path) {
    boolean isExisted = false;
    FileConnection filecon = null;
    try {
        filecon = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path, Connector.READ);
        isExisted = filecon.exists();
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (filecon != null) {
                filecon.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return isExisted;
    }
}

public void playFileFromSDCard() {

    String path1 = "file:///C:/song.mp3";
    String path2 = "file:///E:/song.mp3";

    if (isFileExisted(path1))   {
        try {
            System.out.println("path1 exist -> calling platform request " + path1);
            platformRequest(path1);
        } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (isFileExisted(path2)) {
        try {
            System.out.println("path2 exist -> calling platform request " + path2);
            platformRequest(path2);
        } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("both path doesnt exists");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and i got "path1 exist -> calling platform request file:///C:/song.mp3"

Comment: Check below links. You need to pass the URI instead of path. 1) http://www.javaproblemstips.com/652361/  2) http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/208349-How-to-play-media-file-in-System-media-player-in-j2me

Comment: I followed the sample ways in those links. nothing works. Can you please give me a working example for media files.

Answer (score 0):

After so many searches i found some reasons for the issue. This may help for people in future who is having the same problem. refer the following links.

[Open file with MIDlet.platformRequest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286855/open-file-with-midlet-platformrequest/292309#292309) , 
 [How to play media file in System media player in j2me????](http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/208349-How-to-play-media-file-in-System-media-player-in-j2me)